# mootools :not selector not working

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am working on a site that unfortunately uses mootools. I am trying to trigger an event when any link on the page is clicked apart from if the link has a certain id. Here is my code:

```
$$('a:not(#learn-more)').addEvent('click', function(){
    alert("");
});
```

If i remove the :not(#learn-more) from the selector then the event gets triggered when any link is clicked, but with the :not() in then nothing happens. I don't get any errors or anything just nothing happens. Anyone got any ideas whats going on?

Update: It is using mootools version 1.2.4

Comment: which version of mootools are you using?

Comment: Hi Jon I have updated the question now with the version

Comment: "I am working on a site that unfortunately uses mootools." -- a great way to get help from Mootools devs ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the not selector is broken in version **1.2.4**, I think using `not([id=learn-more])` might work however `not(#learn-more)` will not.

For this to work you will need to upgrade to version **1.3** in which the issue was fixed.